# formatting, Sprintf in R

Tags: r, format, printf

I am very new to this site and I am having an issue using sprintf in R. Briefly what I am trying to do is the following:

I need to create a text file with a header (which is space delimited and has to maintain that particular space), below which I need to copy some numbers made of X rows (depending on the data, I will read a big table made of thousands of line, but for each ID there will be a variable number of rows; this is not a major problem as I can loop through them). My problem is that i cannot align the numbers below the header.

```
setwd("C:\\Example\\formatting")
```

My data are in a CSV format so I read:

```
s100 = read.csv("example.csv", header=T)
```

Then I take the columns I am interested in and transform it in this way:

```
SID1 = as.vector(as.matrix(s100$Row1))
SID2 = as.vector(as.matrix(s100$Row2))
SID3 = as.vector(as.matrix(s100$Row3))
SIDN = as.vector(as.matrix(s100$RowN))
```

Then I have the following (do not worry about the letters, that part up to a certain point is really easy, I got stuck at the end when I need to read the SID:

```
sink("Example.xxx", append = T)
cat("*Some description goes here\n")
```

This goes on an on until I need to put the numbers down. So, when I arrive to this piece:

```
cat("@  SAB   SSD   TAR.....", sep = "\n")
```

I now need to have aligned the numbers under SAB, SSD, TAR... and so on.
So, now I do the following ( I only tried using one column and one header first):

```
cat("SAB ", sep = "\n")
cat(sprintf("%s\n", SID1, sep="\n" ))
```

But, what I get in the end is the following:

```
SAB
0.30
 0.40
 0.50
```

Instead of

```
 SAB    SSD     TAR
0.30   0.40      10
0.40   0.80      40
0.50   0.90      00
....   ....      ...
```

So my two questions are:

1. How to solve the above problem?
2. Since at the beginning of that header I have a "@" spaced before the "SAB" how do I align all my numbers accordingly?

I hope I have been clear and not messy, it seems as a simple solution but my knowledge of R and programming go only up to a certain point.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your call to `sprintf`. `SID1` provides a vector of values but you only have one position in your string that accepts input. How about replacing the last line with

```
 cat(paste(SID1, collapse="\n"))
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

Here's an example that might work (`xx` represents your SID data that have been combined into a matrix or data frame)

```
library(MASS)
xx <- matrix(rnorm(100),10)
write.matrix(round(xx, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! but then if I need to add next to it the other SID...1,2, N...spacing them at a given distance like for example:
@  SAB  SSD     TAR
     0.10  0.09      1.00

Comment: but then if I need to add next to it the other SID...1,2, N...spacing them at a given distance like for example:
'@  SAB  SSD     TAR'
'     0.10  0.09      1.00'
'     0.30  0.10      0.09'
'     ......  ......        .......'

I am trying to write the above line like the Tabular form written above.

Comment: Ah yes. Perhaps you can combine you SIDxx data to a matrix and then use the `write.matrix` function from the MASS package. I'll edit above to give an example

Comment: Great, I will try that tomorrow morning from the office. I will let you know how will it go. I did not think into looking at packages.Thank you for the suggestion!